# getForm with get method - how to bypass redirection?

Tags: r, redirect, rcurl, geturl

I'm struggling with the `getForm` and the problem of redirecting my query. I've tried to experiment with `cookiefile` and `followlocation` as in other topics in Stackoverflow but with no result.

My code:

```
  getForm("http://korpus.pl/poliqarp/poliqarp.php",
          query = "pies", corpus = "2", showMatch = "1",showContext = "3",
          leftContext = "5", rightContext = "5", wideContext = "50", hitsPerPage = "10",              
          .opts = curlOptions(
            verbose = TRUE,
            followlocation=TRUE
            )
      )
```

Am I right that I'm getting the the content of the redirection page? If so how can I bypass it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl = getCurlHandle(cookiefile = "", verbose = TRUE, followlocation=TRUE)

getForm("http://korpus.pl/poliqarp/poliqarp.php",
        query = "pies", corpus = "2", showMatch = "1",showContext = "3",
        leftContext = "5", rightContext = "5", wideContext = "50", hitsPerPage = "10",              
        .opts = curlOptions(
          verbose = TRUE,
          followlocation=TRUE
        )
        , curl = curl)


test1 <- getURL("http://korpus.pl/poliqarp/poliqarp.php", curl = curl)
test2 <- getURL("http://korpus.pl/poliqarp/poliqarp.php", curl = curl)
```

With a bit of persuasion test2 hopefully should contain the results

curl is  a handle that will persist across calls. setting `cookiefile` tells RCurl to store the cookies.
You can access the info in the curl handle using `getCurlInfo(curl)`. For example

```
> cat(getCurlInfo(curl)$cookielist)
korpus.pl   FALSE   /   FALSE   0   PHPSESSID   ark8hbi13e2c4qrp51aq51nj62
```

The getForm call sets the important cookie `PHPSESSID`. The first getURL results in:

```
> library(XML)
> htmlParse(test1)['//h3'][[1]]
<h3>This page will <a href="poliqarp.php">refresh</a> automatically in a second</h3>
```

It tells you it will auto refresh probably with javascript so you need to do this refresh manually by issuing another call.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It works! Just to clarify Can you tell what exactly is done by getCurlHandle?  I suppose that we are creating there a "ghost" cookie which is than followed by getURL. And we we need to call getURL twice?